# How to do sort on XSLT

Tags: xslt

```
  <div id="MySampleListTable">
<table width="80%" class="newClass">
  <tr>
    <xsl:if test="count(List) > 0">
     <td valign =" "top" 
      <table width="100%" class="mygrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <caption></caption>
        <tr style="text-align: left;">
          <th id="ColHeader">
            <div class="colheaderdefault">Default</div>
          </th>
          <xsl:for-each select="Listcol/column">
            <th>
              <xsl:attribute name="Id">
                ColHeader_<xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <div>
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                  ColHeader_<xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test=".='Name'">Name</xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@DisplayName"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </div>
           </th>
         </xsl:for-each>
          <th>
            Date
          </th>
       </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="List"    />
      </table>
       </td>

    </xsl:if>
   </tr>
```

I have the above XSLT and I need to sort this by Name and then by Date.
The column(s) Name and Date has to be clickable and based on the click I should be able to the sort the result.

Any example would be great. Thanks for your support.

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using? Do you need to sort the items in the `for-each`? What does the source XML look like?

Comment: @Kalls: About sorting, you will only get guessing answer because you haven't provided input source. About "onclick", this is out of scope of XSLT. Behavior is Emacscript field.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to handle the sort in the xslt side then change

```
<xsl:for-each select="Listcol/column">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="Listcol/column">
   <xsl:sort select="@name" order="ascending" />
   <xsl:sort select="@date" order="ascending" />
```

---

If you want the whole functionality of a webpage that can sort result based on user interaction, you will have to try yourself and tell us where you stumble..

Comment: I don't have any experience in XSLT. This is an issue I am trying to fix. Yes it has to be based on user interaction. Any example would be of great help. I appreciate your input.

Comment: @Kalls, you ask about sorting with xslt. User interaction with clicking etc has nothing to do with xslt.. Please modify your question to add relevant info .. like what technologies your use asp/php, do you want to sort on the client (*if so do you use a javascript framework*) or on the server. Where is the data coming from .. static xml files or some database (if so which one)..

Comment: I have to step through the code to find all the information. It is asp.net application. I will keep you posted once I have more information.